# Declaring type of function in Haskell (GHCI)?

Tags: haskell

hello there i am new to programming and i am studying haskell language through the book called Learn Yourself Haskell for Great Good. It is found online for free. Anyway there is this chapter called "Types and typeclasses". The writer encouraged reader to do an explicit type declaration for our own fucntion. He gave an example:-

```
addThree :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int  
addThree x y z = x + y + z
```

so i typed the exact thing on my command  prompt(GHCI) but it shows error like this

```
  < interactive > :1:1: error:   
  Variable not in scope:addThree :: Int -> Int -> Int ->Int
```

i even tried copying and paste but it still shwos error
what is wrong and what i can do about it? thanks in advance!